# No funciona en Oracle 11g y en OracleSQLDeveloper si

Tags: oracle

En el OracleSQLDeveloper funciona bien.
Mando ejecutar un .bat en cmd, que manda ejecutar un .sql con, se queda colgado, y tengo que terminarlo.
No reconoce el DECLARE en el Oracle 11g

```
    Este es el .sql:

    SET serveroutput ON
    DECLARE
    ResulCons NUMBER;
    starFlag VARCHAR2(50);

    BEGIN
    starFlag := 'PRUEBA';
    END;

Este es el proceso:
    ***     UPDATE comienza 16:07:52.32                                ***
    ^C¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)? s
    C:\ScriptTst>

Este es el output:
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Lun Ago 14 16:07:52 2023
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

  8
```

Comment: Con el historial de ediciones me percaté que cambiaste totalmente el sentido de la pregunta. Si ya resolviste el problema de que se cuelgue la ejecución, entonces acepta la respuesta que te proveyeron, y _haz una nueva pregunta_.

Comment: Te recomiendo además [eliminar esta otra pregunta](/q/601361) porque tiene muchos errores de tipeo, y eso es motivo suficiente para que termine [cerrada](/help/closed-questions), ya que tal pregunta no será útil para otras personas.

Comment: @padaleiana De la pregunta que me recomiendas cerrar, creo que hay buenas respuestas que merecen no ser borradas, del tipeo te he de comentar que tal vez no tengo el nivel de excelencia que tu tienes o que esperas que todo el mundo tenga, te aseguro que ire refinando los puntos de oportunidad que me mencionan, publico porque necesito el apoyo y/o ayuda de las personas de este foro, y te lo firmo que agradezco enormemente el apoyo que recibo, te mando un abrazo y saludos

Comment: No va por niveles de excelencia, es que es explícitamente un motivo de cierre: _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos._ Y por cierto, en lugar de agradecer por escrito, la forma de agradecer en este sitio (que no es un foro) es _votando a favor_ las respuestas que consideres útiles.

Comment: @Bryro Has trabajado este pase de variables entre .bat y .sql?

Comment: El sitio, no funciona asi. Si te dieron una respuesta, y responde tu pregunta, aceptala, cerra la pregunta, y abri una nueva...

Answer (score 0):

En sqlplus, para ejecutar un bloque de código se requiere utilizar `/` ([*slash*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/slash.html#GUID-F5EEC10C-6E74-4CCE-A196-C591F83C3D44)), por lo que en tu código simplemente defines pero no haces más y queda a la espera.

Por lo que tu código quedaría:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
ResulCons NUMBER;
starFlag VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
starFlag := 'PRUEBA';
--- imprimir valor
dbms_output.put_line(starFlag );
END;
/
```

Comment: Bryro, ya funciono, Muchas Gracias. Una pregunta en el .sql le asigno un valor a la variable starFlag, que tengo que hacer para la reciba el .bat de donde fue llamado?

Comment: ya te agrege como imprimir

Comment: El DBMS...ya lo había utilizado. En el .sql le asigno un valor a la variable starFlag. Hay una manera de pasar el valor de la variable starFlag al .bat que mando llamar el .sql. Gracias

Comment: Esta respuesta también responde a [esta pregunta](/q/601361) @JavierNunez. De esto te hablaba en los comentarios de esa pregunta.